# Detect an odd-length cycle from a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

so my goal is to detect an odd-cycle in a directed graph. I know for the undirected graph, the graph contains the odd-cycle iff it's non-bipartile. So I can check whether or not the graph is bipartile. If it is then the undirected graph doesn't contain the odd-cycle, otherwise it does.

For the directed graph, does the same algorithm apply? Do I need more condition for the directed graph to have odd-length cycle?

Thanks

Comment: What do you consider a cycle in a directed graph? Do you mean a cycle in the underlying undirected graph, or do you want a *directed cycle*: a connected subgraph with in-degree=out-degree=1 for each vertex?

Comment: I want to find a directed cycle in a directed graph, ex: A->B->c->A. Thank you